# css3 flexbox horizontal align in absolute div

Tags: firefox, css, flexbox

I have an absolute positioned div with a `display: box`

In Chrome it works perfectly fine, the children of the div align horizontally, but in Firefox it doesn't seem to work.

If I remove the `position: absolute` it works fine in both browsers, but I need it.

Example: http://dabblet.com/gist/1716069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The experimental display types you're using mean totally different things, and none of them match `display: box` for the simple reason that this last doesn't exist and never will (the CSS spec will be using `display: flexbox`, with quite different behavior from all the prefixed "box" displays, all of which have very different behavior from each other).

Since they mean different things, browsers handle the section of CSS that says that absolutely positioned elements have their display values changed to `block` or `table` somewhat differently.  Gecko changes `-moz-box` to `block`.  WebKit doesn't change `-webkit-box` to anything else.

I suggest not using experimental display types that are going to disappear in the not too far off future.  If you *do* have to use them, you probably want to wrap a block around your "box" and position that block.

Comment: thanks, I was just trying it out, but I already had an JavaScript fallback for it. So I'll just use that